# Trying to update data in 2 tables

Tags: php, mysql, database

Here is the code :

```
  if ($param1 == 'do_update') {
            $data['student_id']         = $this->input->post('student_id');
            $data['title']              = html_escape($this->input->post('title'));
            if ($this->input->post('description') != null) {
                $data['description']        = html_escape($this->input->post('description'));
            }

            $data['amount']             = html_escape($this->input->post('amount'));
            $data['amount_paid']        = html_escape($this->input->post('amount_paid'));
            $data2['amount']            = html_escape($this->input->post('amount'));

            /*$data['status']             = $this->input->post('status');*/
            $data['creation_timestamp'] = strtotime($this->input->post('date'));

            $this->db->where('invoice_id', $param2);
            $this->db->update('invoice', $data);
            $this->db->where('invoice_id', $param2);
            $this->db->update('payment', $data2);
```

- 2 tables Invoice and Payment... I can update data in "invoice table"
  with a specific ID, but also at the same time, it is updating the
  whole column in the "Payment table" instead of that specific ID. I
  can tell doing something wrong in the last 4 lines.

$data fields are of Invoice Table and
$data2 fields are of Payment table

Invoice_id is common in both tables..

Comment: what is error you are facing?

Comment: 2 tables Invoice and Payment... I can update data in "invoice table" with a specific ID, but ERROR is, it isalso at the same time, it is updating the whole column in the "Payment table" instead of that specific ID. I can tell doing something wrong in the last 4 lines

Comment: Can you please add both table fields in your question?

Comment: $data fields are of Invoice Table and
$data2 fields are of Payment table

Invoice_id is common in both tables..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't actually using your where conditions.  Try:

```
$this->db->where('invoice_id', $param2)->update('invoice', $data);
$this->db->where('invoice_id', $param2)->update('payment', $data2);
```